# CICD for synapse

Tags: branch, azure-synapse, cicd

I would like to automate deployment from Dev to other synapse workspaces, so I am going to use CICD pipelines to achieve this, but I would like to know how to configure CD to deploy just a specific notebook or script, but not all notebook?

Thank you

I tried to set trigger on specific branch on CD (release pipeline)